# In Django, ok to set Model.objects to another manager outside of model definition?

Tags: python, django

Suppose, in Django 1.6, you have the following model code:

```
class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset():
        return ... # i.e. return a custom queryset

class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_manager = FooManager()
```

If, outside the `Foo` model definition (e.g. in view code or in the shell), you do:

```
Foo.objects = FooManager()
Foo.objects.all()
```

you'll get an exception in the Django internal code on `Foo.objects.all()` due to a variable named `lookup_model` being `None'.

However, if you instead do:

```
Foo.objects = Foo.foo_manager
Foo.objects.all()
```

The `Foo.objects.all()` will work as expected, i.e. as if `objects` had been defined to be `FooManager()` in the model definition in the first place.

I believe this behavior is due to Django working its "magic" in creating managers during model definition (just as it works magic in creating model fields).

My question: is there any reason NOT to assign `objects` to an alternate manager in this way outside of the model definition? It seems to work fine, but I don't fully understand the internals so want to make sure.

In case you are wondering, the context is that I have a large code base with many typical references to `objects`. I want to have this code base  work on different databases dynamically, i.e. based on a request URL parameter. My plan is to use middleware that sets `objects` for all relevant models to managers that point to the appropriate database. The rest of the app code would then go on its merry way, using `objects` without ever having to know anything has changed.

Comment: We have done this not by changing objects everywhere, but by writing a middleware that sets the relevant data on the request, makes request globally available using django-tls, and then a database router that decides the database using that.

Comment: Similarly you could make a .objects manager that decided which sub-manager to call based on the request, but database routers seem cleaner for database routing.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich - thanks for the tip. To make sure I understand, basically you are using django-tls as the mechanism for the middleware to communicate to the database router? (I agree database router is the more natural place for this logic.)

Comment: Yes, basically. Normally database routers don't know anything about requests, so we chose to cheat a little. I thought it was quite a scary hack at first, but it's been running for a couple of years without trouble now. You need something similar to choose a database for when there is no request, running management commands and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is that this is not at all thread safe. Doing this will change the definition for all requests being served by that process, until something else changes it again. That is very likely to have all sorts of unexpected effects.

Comment: Ah yes. That's quite the deal-killer. Thanks.

Comment: May I ask your opinion of @RemcoGerlich's suggests (in comments to the question) of using django-tls for thread-local storage?

Comment: I've not used that, and generally I'm suspicious of thread-locals (following the advice of the Django core devs) although I can't see anything obviously wrong with it from a safety point of view.

Comment: Django uses thread-local global variables in some places, and so do other frameworks, e.g. Flask uses them for requests. Django decided to go another route in the case of request objects, and pass them explicitly to middleware and views. There are good reasons to avoid global variables, but sometimes they don't outweigh the benefits. I'm not sure if that's the case here, though. In views and middleware you have the request available, and you can use `Manager.db_manager` to override the database router. If that doesn't cut it, you might indeed need django-tls.